# Performance of truncate and insert vs update

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with more than 1 million records and table is growing everyday.I need to update two columns of that table everyday. What is the best way either to truncate the table and insert or update row wise?

example :-

today

```
userid activitycount 
1         18
```

tomorrow

```
userid  activitycount
1        19
```

Comment: I would change the application logic so that you don't need to update 1+ million rows every day. Sorry for such a bad advice, but I felt like I have to write that...

Comment: The best way to find out would be to *benchmark* it. It's a reasonably short query to write either way, so entirely reasonable to simply test-run it.

Comment: If you truncate the table all rows are completely removed. So you also lose the information stored in the other columns of the table and you can't update it any more. I don't see how you could possibly think truncate is an alternative to update.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the use case is I have to create a summary table based on user activity. even if I truncate and reload it will not affect other rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is faster to truncate table and copy it again. On Postgres docs you can learn [how to do to populate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html) tables with big datasets:

> This section contains some suggestions on how to make this process as efficient as possible.

- **Use [Copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)**: *Use COPY to load all the rows in one command, instead of using a series of INSERT commands.*
- **Remove Indexes**: if you need indexes, just create indexes when data is already inserted.
- **Remove Foreign Key Constraints**: Create constraints when data is already inserted.
- **Tuning Postgres installation**: maintenance_work_mem, max_wal_size, Disable WAL Archival and Streaming Replication, ...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `fillfactor` of the table is less than 50 and that the updated columns are not indexed.

Then the updates will become HOT updates that don't need to modify any index, and autovacuum will make sure that tomorrow's update will find enough free space.

The disadvantage is the bloat you have with this method, but you don't need to create new tables and rename them, which may be problematic with concurrent transactions.